# How to open an excel sheet using Java?

Tags: java, excel

I am trying to make a program through which i want to manipulate data in the excel sheet,
But data is being manipulated only when the excel sheet is open.
whats the process to open and close it using java coding.

Comment: you can use apache poi (http://poi.apache.org/) for accessing excel sheets in java.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [POI](http://poi.apache.org/) to read and write Excel sheets.

This article is interesting to understand how to use it :

http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/04/16/poi_excel.html

Comment: I am using JEXCEL ,whats the process to open through it

Answer (score 0):

Hey look, there's a tutorial on how to do this link from the JExecel website!

http://www.andykhan.com/jexcelapi/tutorial.html

Side note: It looks like JExcel is file based only. This means you can't interact with an open spreadsheet. If you need to interact with an open spreadsheet you will have to use JNI or a library such as [J-Integra COM](http://j-integra.intrinsyc.com/), which uses JNI.

Comment: Thanks alot. I feel this tutorial will help me alot